# How to create aligned index (PK) on partitioned table and delete the non-aligned index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a large partitioned table by month (70 Billion rows)

It has 2 indexes

1. Clustered index on deviceId, logDateTime, eventId, id (unique)
2. Non Clustered index on id (unique) - Primary Key

the first clustered index is aligned with the partitions, the 2nd non-clustered Primary key is non-aligned on the primary filegroup

I want to align the 2nd nonclustered index with the partition to make it easy to truncate parttion data etc.

from what i've read I need to drop the index and recreate it, can i create it first then delete the old one and set the new one as a primary key?

I'm looking for a solution with the least/ no downtime since its a 24/7 database

Sql server 2017 enterprise

the current bad index is

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LogData] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_LogData] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = ON, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 99) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

When i look at creating a new index, I either have a file group or partition scheme
if I choose the partition scheme there is only one called **PartitionByMonthScheme** and it only allows me to choose datetime as the column, this generates the follow

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_newindex_id] ON [dbo].[LogData]
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PartitionByMonthScheme]([LogDateTime])
```

I'm assuming this is correct, and after I do tis it will align the new index with the partition? and then i have to delete the old PK index and make this new index the primary key?

or should i be unlinking the primary key first and then doing the index creation with primary key as one operation?

Advice and help on achieving the above will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You need to add a column LogDateTime in your new unique index to be able to align it. So you don't have to drop the old one. After creating index you just need to change a PK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aligned means the table (clustered index here) and all non-clustered indexes must be partitioned using the same partition scheme or partition schemes based on the same partition function. This ensures partition boundaries are identical to permit partition-level operations like `TRUNCATE` or `SWITCH`.

The issue you have is that the partitioning column must be a key column of partitioned primary keys (as well as partitioned unique indexes and unique constraints). Consequently, you will need to add `logDateTime` to the primary key in order to align the table/indexes.

Before you go there, I suggest you first verify the primary key is actually needed/used. Log tables are often not part of a relational model and thus do not require a primary key (although common in the wild in my experience). If that is your situation, simply drop the PK to align the table.

Assuming the application does not require a primary key on `id` alone, you can create a new unique index (or unique constraint) on `id` and `logDateTime` and drop the old primary key afterwards like below.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_LogData] ON dbo.LogData
    (
        id ASC
       ,logDateTime
    ) 
    WITH (ONLINE = ON)
    ON PartitionByMonthScheme(logDateTime);
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.LogData DROP CONSTRAINT PK_LogData;
GO
```

Alignment is not an option if you must have a primary key on `id` alone.

Comment: thanks, we do require the id since the (IOT) devices table has a latestRecordId column for fast lookups of latest data, but i dont think it has to be primary key ?

Comment: @Quade, is the `latestRecordId` the same as the `id` column in your question? Is it an IDENTITY column? The composite unique index I suggested won't enforce uniqueness on `id` alone but it will help optimize singleton lookups.

Comment: yes, ```devices.latestRecordId``` points to the ```LogData.id``` table for singleton lookups, and the ```LogData.id``` PK is a bigint with IDENTITY seed that auto accumulates

Comment: @Quade, as long as no foreign keys reference `LogData`, you should be able to align the table/indexes as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: thanks @Dan, so the table does not need a primary key then? and i can create a unique non clustered index with ```id,logDateTime```, and when i do sington lookups i must use ```id``` and ```logdatetime```? or will using the ```id``` alone on lookups still perform ok?

Comment: sorry meant to say: turns out ```logData.id``` is not referenced by any foreign key

Comment: @Quade, with a unique non-clustered partitioned index (or primary key or unique constraint) on both columns, a singleton lookup using `id` alone will need to touch every monthly partition because partitions cannot be eliminated without `logDateTime`. SQL Server will perform a seek for each partition even though the requested row exists in only one partition. Performance will depend on the number of partitions and frequency of such queries. I can't say if performance will be ok without knowing more about the workload and SLAs. Queries should ideally specify `logDateTime` too, if possible.

Comment: yes understood, so as long as we query by the latest id and latest datetime then the query will touch the 1 partition (patitions are by month), we store this so should be able to do that by adjusting the latest record queries

Comment: in regards to deployment of the new index, i assume if we use ```with online = on``` on the new index it will not lock/block anything, how about dropping the old primary key index, would that cause locking/blocking and would we reclaim the space by dropping the primary key index?

Comment: also... is there compression available for this type of index?, we use row compression on clustered index

Comment: @Quade, the `DATA_COMPRESSION=ROW` clause can be specified for the new index (and non-clustered indexes in general). Same with [ONLINE=ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#online---on--off-), which will allow concurrent DML operations. A brief SCH-M lock will be needed at the end of the online operation and this can block or be blocked by other activity. Specify the `WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY` option to control the behavior as desired.

Comment: A SCH-M lock will be needed when the old PK is dropped. However, most of the work (reclaiming space) happens after the drop completes by a background task. The drop itself is fairly fast.